# How to diplay gif image in Jypyter Notebook based on conditions?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gif

The problem: I am trying to create a simple quiz and display a gif image based on the score.
See the score category below:

- Full score: 5
- Awesome: 5
- Not bad: 3 - 4
- Bad:0-2

I am able to display a single gif by using the following
`from IPython.display import Image`
`Image(url='https://images.gr-assets.com/hostedimages/1555943935ra/27397694.gif', width=375, height=200)`

But, I am able to get the gif displayed based on the following logic. Hope someone can help me solve this issue. Thank you!

```
if score==5:
   Image(url='https://images.gr-assets.com/hostedimages/1555943935ra/27397694.gif', width=375, height=200) 
   print("Awesome!")

elif score>2 and score<=4:
    Image(url='https://media3.giphy.com/media/l0HepmE7eqiK86GSQ/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e473mzzo1br8w9didsqr5j34nruzuks3wlvxmxf2zse&rid=giphy.gif', width=375, height=200)
    print("Not bad!")

if score<=2:
    Image(url='https://media1.tenor.com/images/ea96c313bbb74cc69abc861e21ee3098/tenor.gif', width=375, height=200) 
    print("Bad!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display` to plot the image.

```
if score==5:
   img = Image(url='https://images.gr-assets.com/hostedimages/1555943935ra/27397694.gif', width=375, height=200) 
   display(img)
   print("Awesome!")

elif score>2 and score<=4:
    img = Image(url='https://media3.giphy.com/media/l0HepmE7eqiK86GSQ/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e473mzzo1br8w9didsqr5j34nruzuks3wlvxmxf2zse&rid=giphy.gif', width=375, height=200)
    display(img)
    print("Not bad!")

elif score<=2:
    img = Image(url='https://media1.tenor.com/images/ea96c313bbb74cc69abc861e21ee3098/tenor.gif', width=375, height=200) 
    display(img)
    print("Bad!")
```